# Error: <rect> attribute and Expected length d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I am new in d3.js, and I have a sample CSV file like this

```
country, year
China 1,1998-12-1
China 2,1999-12-1
China 3,2000-12-1
Indonesia 1,1999-12-1
Indonesia 2,1999-12-1
Indonesia 3,1998-12-1
Russia 1,1999-12-1
Russia 2,1998-12-1
Russia 3,1999-12-1
Russia 4,1998-12-1
```

After I finish and show the x-axis and y-axis, I can not create and show bars corresponding and show the bar. here is the full code

```
import { 
  select,
  csv,
  scaleLinear,
  max,
  scaleBand,
  axisLeft,
    axisBottom} 
from 'd3';

const svg = select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const render = data =>{
  const margin = { top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 20, left: 100 };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  const ChinaFilter = data.filter(function(d){ 
    return d.country.match ('China');
  });
  const IndonesiaFilter = data.filter(function(d){ 
    return d.country.match ('Indonesia');
  });
  const RussiaFilter = data.filter(function(d){ 
    return d.country.match ('Russia');
  });
  var Filter = [ChinaFilter.length,IndonesiaFilter.length,RussiaFilter.length];
  var countryFilter = ['China','Indonesia','Russia'];


  const xScale = scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, max(Filter)])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);


  const yScale = scaleBand()
    .domain(countryFilter)
    .range([0, innerHeight])
        .padding(0.1);


const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  g.append('g').call(axisLeft(yScale));
  g.append('g').call(axisBottom(xScale))
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${innerHeight})`);

    g.selectAll('rect').data(data)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('y', yScale(countryFilter))
    .attr('width', xScale(Filter))
    .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth());


};

csv('data.csv').then(data => {
    render(data);
});
```

The actual results[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFJNU.png

The expected output should be (China,3) (Indonesia,3) (Russia,4) in bar-chart format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, the main one being the `data` array. If this is your CSV:

```
country, year
China 1,1998-12-1
China 2,1999-12-1
China 3,2000-12-1
Indonesia 1,1999-12-1
Indonesia 2,1999-12-1
Indonesia 3,1998-12-1
Russia 1,1999-12-1
Russia 2,1998-12-1
Russia 3,1999-12-1
Russia 4,1998-12-1
```

It means that your `data` is an array with 10 objects, and therefore we expect to see 10 bars in the bar chart. That's not the case. Since you just want to show the number of records for each country, let's create a correct data array, here named `correctData`:

```
var countryFilter = ['China', 'Indonesia', 'Russia'];
var correctData = countryFilter.map(function(d) {
    return {
      country: d,
      length: data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.country.match(d);
      }).length
    }
});
```

Then, we change the scales:

```
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(correctData, function(d) {
      return d.length
    })])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);

const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(correctData.map(function(d) {
      return d.country
    }))
    .range([0, innerHeight])
    .padding(0.1);
```

And finally, use the **datum** for creating the bars:

```
g.selectAll('rect').data(correctData)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.country)
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.length)
    })
    .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth());
```

Some final considerations: it's not clear to me why you are mixing `var` and `const`. Also, avoid white spaces in your CSV.

Here is your code with those changes:

```js
const csv = `country, year
China 1,1998-12-1
China 2,1999-12-1
China 3,2000-12-1
Indonesia 1,1999-12-1
Indonesia 2,1999-12-1
Indonesia 3,1998-12-1
Russia 1,1999-12-1
Russia 2,1998-12-1
Russia 3,1999-12-1
Russia 4,1998-12-1`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const render = data => {
  const margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 100
  };
  const innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
  const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var countryFilter = ['China', 'Indonesia', 'Russia'];
  var correctData = countryFilter.map(function(d) {
    return {
      country: d,
      length: data.filter(function(e) {
        return e.country.match(d);
      }).length
    }
  });

  const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(correctData, function(d) {
      return d.length
    })])
    .range([0, innerWidth]);

  const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(correctData.map(function(d) {
      return d.country
    }))
    .range([0, innerHeight])
    .padding(0.1);

  const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

  g.append('g').call(d3.axisLeft(yScale));
  g.append('g').call(d3.axisBottom(xScale))
    .attr('transform', `translate(0,${innerHeight})`);

  g.selectAll('rect').data(correctData)
    .enter().append('rect')
    .attr('y', function(d) {
      return yScale(d.country)
    })
    .attr('width', function(d) {
      return xScale(d.length)
    })
    .attr('height', yScale.bandwidth());
};

render(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="200"></svg>
```

Comment: In fact, I have more complicated files to handle, this sample CSV is used for me to practice. Your feedback is very helpful to me. Thank you!